# call web service in a managed bean

Tags: web-services, jsf, jax-ws

I have developed a web service with JAX-WS and test it on a main class it works fine. I follow [this tutorial](http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jax-ws/create-and-consume-web-service-using-jax-ws/). But when I try to call it from a managed bean in a JSF page, it don't work. Here is my managed bean :

```
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import client.Calculator;
import client.CalculatorService;

public class addBean {

    private int n1;
    private int n2;
    private int somme;
         public addBean() {
    }

    public int getN1() {
        return n1;
    }

    public void setN1(int n1) {
        this.n1 = n1;
    }

    public int getN2() {
        return n2;
    }

    public void setN2(int n2) {
        this.n2 = n2;
    }

    public int getSomme() {
        return somme;
    }

    public void setSomme(int somme) {
        this.somme = somme;
    }

    public void countListener (ActionEvent event){
        CalculatorService calcService = new CalculatorService();
        Calculator calc = calcService.getCalculatorPort();
        somme = calc.add(n1, n2);  
    }
}
```

the error is

```
    javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
```

Comment: Your problem looks more like you can't connect to your web service provider. Test your web service first and then make sure you're calling the right namespace in the WS-consume generated classes.

Comment: That's a wrapper exception. Please lookup the root cause in the stacktrace. *That* is the root cause of your problem. In the future questions, please post the entire stacktrace directly.